# google-services json missing client_type 3

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I use Firebase for many features and one of them is the Google sign-in.
About a year ago I created an App assigned the SHA1 to it and downloaded the json file.
All worked great until last week I had to add another app to the same project in Firebase and redownloaded the json file.
For some reason the R.string.default_web_client_id is not exist.
The reason for it is the new json file does not contain the web type auth client in its clients list.
I can copy the client ID to the strings.xml but it should be generated automatically.

Comment: What's the problem in coping?

Comment: First, let's say I have multiple projects of Firebase for the same app ( QA - Production), and I don't want to handle this situation. Second, it should be generated by its default behavior so coping it makes me feels like a bad approach.

Comment: Multiple projects simultaneously for single app? I haven't done that before:-!

Comment: Why not? https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

Comment: Okay I check that out. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue and what I found is that:

- When you create the firebase project it creates a web OAuth client in console.developer.google.com, which's the one that is included in the `google-services.json` of each android app you create in that project.
- If you had deleted that manually, then to restore it you need to add a web app in firebase and then it will recreate that web OAuth client, and then the `google-services.json` will contain that.

I hope these two findings helps you